# How to open google hangouts by using Intents?

Tags: android, android-intent, hangouts-api

However, I want to pass the name or ID of the person I want to call--the recipient name. I can't figure this out.

I have tried below code. its working fine. But I want to open hangouts with specific user id.

```
Intent hangouts = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_SEND);
hangouts.setPackage("com.google.android.talk");
hangouts.setType("text/plain");
hangouts.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_TEXT, "text message " + ": \n" + " for opening hangout");
startActivity(Intent.createChooser(hangouts, "Hangouts is not installed."));
```

Comment: Let me know, if any other way to achieve this.

Comment: please note that hangouts is going to be something like deprecated AFAIK

Comment: Thanks for the info.

Comment: I have some doubts about hangout api. If we create an event for specific user id in google calendar, in that calendar we can open google hangout message for that specific user.

Then  we can also integrate hangout icon in out app right?. Any one can explain whether we have the possibility to implement or not?